# Scrollbar на всю высоту блока, CSS

Tags: css3

На картинке видно текущий скроллбар, нужно его перенести на всю высоту экрана.
Попробовал сделать див(с position:relative) а в нем див со скроллом Position:absolute; и выровнял по всем сторонам, внутри него сделал див с margin-top:20 vh; получилось что скроллбар на всю высоту а блок там где и нужно и отсюда следующая проблема, при скролле нижний блок налазит на верхний.
На втором изображении видна проблема.

```
<div style="position:relative;"><!-- чтобы блок с Position:absolute брал его размеры -->
    <div class="scroll" style="position: absolute;right: 0;top:0;left:0;height: 80vh;overflow-y:auto;">
        <div style="position: relative;top:20vh;left:0;right:0;">
            <div>...</div>
            <div>...</div>
            <div>...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нарисуй как должно быть

Comment: Первый img как должно быть нарисовано

Comment: без реальной страницы html трудней найти как исправить

Answer (score 0):

Сделай все блоки кроме того, который по центру, `position:fixed`